# Session scoped managed bean and actionListener

Tags: session, jsf

I want to do multiple actions on different managed beans with the same button, one being scoped session and the other request. In my example I use the same bean for both.

index.xhtml

```
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton image="ui-icon ui-icon-notice" action="#{controller.inc()}" update="result">
            <f:actionListener type="controller.Controller" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:form>

    <p:panel id="result">
        #{controller.count}
    </p:panel>
```

controller.Controller.java

```
@Named(value = "controller")
@SessionScoped
public class Controller implements ActionListener, Serializable
{
    int count = 0;

    public Controller(){
        System.out.println("new");
    }

    public void inc(){
        count += 1;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException{
        count += 1000;
    }
}
```

When I press the button the count increases by 1, instead of 1001, and creates a new bean. What did I do wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's expected behaviour. The `<f:actionListener type>` creates and gets its own bean instance on every declaration. It does not reuse the same session scoped bean which is managed by JSF.

You need to use `binding` instead to bind to the already-created session scoped bean instance.

```
<f:actionListener binding="#{controller}" />
```