# `ViewScoped` bean gets re-created after `<f:actionListener>` added?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, view-scope

My JSF backing bean is `ViewScoped`.
Since I've added another action listener, the bean gets re-created even the view hasn't changed.

```
@ManagedBean (name="EncryptionBean")
@ViewScoped
public class EncryptionBean extends ClientBeanBase implements Serializable, ActionListener 
{
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent arg0) throws AbortProcessingException 
    {
       refresh();
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<p:commandButton value="OK" type="submit" actionListener="#{FileSelectBean.actionOk}" oncomplete="dlgFileSelect.hide();" update=":formEncryptionDialog,:formTranscodingPage:streamInfoId" styleClass="buttonOK">        
    <f:actionListener type="com.company.rews.webclient.beans.EncryptionBean" />
</p:commandButton>
```

When I press `OK` button, I wouldn't expect that the bean is created again since it is `ViewScoped`, however it gets re-created (constructor called) and I loose some variables. When I remove the `<f:actionListener>` line, the been is not re-created on `OK`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:
[Session scoped managed bean and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675319/session-scoped-managed-bean-and-actionlistener)

Instead of `type` one needs to use `binding`:

```
<f:actionListener binding="#{BackingBean}"/>
```