# Injecting a CDI SessionScoped bean into a JSF ValueChangeListener

Tags: jsf, cdi, valuechangelistener

I am trying to use a `javax.faces.event.ValueChangeListener` against a `h:selectOneMenu` like so

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{localeBean.languageCode}" onchange="submit()">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="English" itemValue="en" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="German" itemValue="de" />
    <f:valueChangeListener  type="org.bitbucket.paulstat.jsf.event.ExampleValueChangeListener" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is the listener

```
import javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeListener;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.bitbucket.paulstat.jsf.localisation.LocaleBean;

public class ExampleValueChangeListener implements ValueChangeListener {

    @Inject
    private LocaleBean localeBean;

    @Override
    public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        localeBean.setLanguageCode(event.getNewValue().toString());
        localeBean.switchLocale();
    }

}
```

And the `LocaleBean`

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleBean implements Serializable {

    private String languageCode;

    public void switchLocale() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale(languageCode));
    }

    public void setLanguageCode(String languageCode) {
        this.languageCode = languageCode;
    }

    public String getLanguageCode() {
        return languageCode;
    }

}
```

The `LocaleBean` doesn't appear to be being injected in the value change listener and is null. Can we mix SessionScoped CDI beans with JSF ValueChangeListeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Inject` works only in CDI managed beans. Your `ExampleValueChangeListener` isn't a CDI managed bean.

Make it one. Easiest way is to put the `@Named` annotation on it so it's available in EL.

```
@Named
public class ExampleValueChangeListener implements ValueChangeListener {
    // ...
}
```

Reference it via `binding` instead of `type`.

```
<f:valueChangeListener binding="#{exampleValueChangeListener}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How to inject in @FacesValidator with @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572335/how-to-inject-in-facesvalidator-with-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autow)
- [How to inject @EJB, @PersistenceContext, @Inject, @Autowired, etc in @FacesConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665673/how-to-inject-ejb-persistencecontext-inject-autowired-etc-in-facesconve)
- [Session scoped managed bean and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675319/session-scoped-managed-bean-and-actionlistener/)